# Semantic UI - Search input - add value to the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have below input:

```
<div class="ui search kunde-search">
    <input class="semantic-input prompt" value="" name="client" type="text" placeholder="Common passwords...">
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

I am using the semantic-ui in order to use the search function, which then search my database for specific stuff:

```
  $('.kunde-search')
  .search({
    apiSettings: {
      url: '/api/softbox/retrieve_clients&q={query}',
    },

    onResponse: function(response) {
        return response;
    },
    onSelect: function(result){
        console.log(result.client_id);
        $('.semantic-input').val(result.client_id);
    },

    minCharacters : 3
  });
```

The `result.client_id` value is correct, and is populated. The console log shows the correct value. However, I am not able to add this value to the `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, it worked to just scrap the `return false;` statement and use it like this:

```
onSelect: function(result){
             $('input[name="client_id"]').val(result.client_id);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `return false` after changing input value like,

```
onSelect: function(result){
    console.log(result.client_id);
    $('.semantic-input').val(result.client_id); // add id
    $('.results').removeAttr('style').hide(); // hide it forcefully
    return false; // prevent default functionality.
},
```

Comment: This almost works. I can select the value and it populates the input - however, the .results div don't hides when I choose the value